# Calculus 3 Integration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

Suppose I have to evaluate the line integral of:

$\int_{c}xye^{yz}dy$

Where $c$ is parametrized by: 
$x=t$, $y=t^2$, $z=t^3$, $0\leq t\leq1$

This gives me:

$\int_{0}^{1}2t^4e^{t^5}\sqrt{9t^4+4t^2+1} dt$

Correct so far? If so, I'm really stumped on how to integrate this, one idea I have is completing the square of the expression under the square root, but I'm not too sure.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the root in the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is much simpler:
$$
\int_{c}xye^{yz}dy=\int_{c}0\,dx+xye^{yz}dy+0\,dz=\int_{0}^{1}2t^4e^{t^5} dt.
$$

Comment: Don't we also add on the square root of the squares of the derivatives?

Comment: Oh, this is a vector field correct?

Comment: Right, you are thinking of something else (perhaps you have written it $ds$).

Comment: That's it, thanks.